# iOS-optimized png with transparency

Tags: ios, optimization, png

I'm using this excellent [OptimizedPNG](https://github.com/basuke/OptimizedPNG) for downloaded (not Xcode bundled) images, but it appears to turn transparent pixels black. Is there a similar utility (optimized using CgBI format) that works for PNGs that include transparency?

example usage as requested:

```
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:IMAGE_URL]]];
NSData *data = [image optimizedData];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"optimized-image.png"];
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:filePath contents:data attributes:nil];
```

Comment: I'm curious why you optimize images in iOS (presumably after they have already been downloaded)

Comment: It is optimized for display. Normal unoptimized PNGs are slow to display on iPhone. The difference is huge.

Comment: Can you post a usage example? I want to try to fix OptimizedPNG.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CGContext drawing with premultiplied alpha](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11980019/cgcontext-drawing-with-premultiplied-alpha)

Answer (score 1):

Easy answer: Forget "optimized PNGs".

http://imageoptim.com/tweetbot.html

http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/10/avoiding-image-decompression-sickness/

I am using PNGOUT to compress the images as good as possible and I can
verify that there is no difference in speed.

Comment: The second link indicates crushed PNGs are indeed 50% faster than unoptimized PNGs. That is what I'm looking for.

Comment: In "Avoiding decompression sickness" there are also tips to trick the UIImage in loading its content and holding the image in its uncompressed form.

Answer (score 0):

try setting the UIImageView's backgroundColor property to [UIColor clearColor];

Comment: It has nothing to do with UIImageView. The resulting image does not retain the original alpha.