# PNG Image with BGRA CgBI premultiplied alpha

Tags: ios, core-graphics, cgcontext, alpha-transparency, premultiplied-alpha

I have PNGs in Apple's iOS optimized BGRA PNG format (what I get using [OptimizedPNG](https://github.com/basuke/OptimizedPNG)) and want to draw them in a way that tells CoreGraphics NOT to ignore the alpha component of the image. I'm drawing to a `CGContextRef` in `drawRect:`

Edit: the rendered image shows black where it should be fully transparent (sometimes other random artifacts). The opaque areas are rendered normally.
`CGImageAlphaInfo` I get from the image is `kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast`, which *seems* to indicate there is a problem in the way the image is saved by OptimizedPNG. I think this should be `kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast`.

Perhaps the PNG chunks are wrong, but I don't see anything wrong with IHDR, and there is very little I can find about the CgBI chunk.

This is how OptimizedPNG saves the color data:

```
// IDAT
int size = width*height*4;
unsigned char *buffer = malloc(size);
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(buffer, width, height, 8, width*4, CGImageGetColorSpace(originalImage.CGImage), kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, (CGFloat)width, (CGFloat)height);
CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, originalImage.CGImage);
CGContextRelease(context);

int size_line = 1 + width*4;
int size_in = height*size_line;
unsigned char *buffer_in = malloc(size_in);
for(int y = 0; y < height; ++y){
    unsigned char *src = &buffer[y*width*4];
    unsigned char *dst = &buffer_in[y*size_line];
    *dst++ = 1;
    unsigned char r = 0, g = 0, b = 0, a = 0;
    for(int x = 0; x < width; ++x){
        dst[0] = src[2] - b;
        dst[1] = src[1] - g;
        dst[2] = src[0] - r;
        dst[3] = src[3] - a;
        r = src[0], g = src[1], b = src[2], a = src[3];
        src += 4;
        dst += 4;
    }
}
```

Comment: Core Graphics honors the image's alpha channel, if it has one.  Core Graphics transparency layers actually have little to do with image alpha.  Please post a screen shot of the result you're getting, and describe how you want it to be different.

Comment: @robmayoff edited with more information.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your PNG is lacking an alpha channel.

Maybe there's a bug in OptimizedPNG; I don't know.  Try using `UIImagePNGRepresentation`.

Maybe your original image had no alpha channel.  You can check that in Preview (Tools > Show Inspector, then look for "Has Alpha" in More Info > General).

Also make sure your view's `opaque` is NO and its `backgroundColor` is `clearColor`.  If you're not drawing to the context created by the system, make sure you're creating the context with an alpha channel.

Based on your comments, I tested this code on my iPad 3 running iOS 5.1.1:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fb/Wikisource-logo.png"]]];
NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
NSURL *documentDirectoryURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask].lastObject;
NSURL *url = [documentDirectoryURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.png"];
[data writeToURL:url atomically:YES];
```

Then I copied `test.png` from my device using the Xcode Organizer.  I opened the file in Preview to check it.  It still had an alpha channel.

If you're still having trouble, you need to show us *all* of the code involved in manipulating the image, because you're leaving something out.  Edit your question to include more details and code.

Comment: I tried UIImagePNGRepresentation, the image created using the data from UIImagePNGRepresentation also has no alpha: `kCGImageAlphaNone`, so the image is wrong! The original image definitely has alpha.

Comment: You need to show us the code that creates or loads the image that you're passing to `UIImagePNGRepresentation`.

Comment: The image is downloaded from a server like this: `UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fb/Wikisource-logo.png"]]];`

Comment: I think I misunderstood. I used `UIImagePNGRepresentation()` only to confirm that the image created using OptimizedPNG did in fact have no alpha according to `CGImageGetAlphaInfo()`. I know `UIImagePNGRepresentation()` creates an image with proper alpha when used directly. But, are you saying UIImagePNGRepresentation() optimizes data as BGRA? If it was, it would not be viewable in Preview.

Comment: The easiest way for you to figure out if OptimizedPNG is the problem is to take my test code, put it in your project, replace `UIImagePNGRepresentation` with `OptimizedPNG`, and see if it creates a`test.png` with alpha.  If so, the problem is elsewhere.  If not, the problem is OptimizedPNG.

Comment: The problem is indeed in OptimizedPNG.

Answer (score 0):

From what you've told us there is no reason to use a transparency layer. Transparency layers are used to combine two or more objects to yield a composite graphic that is treated as a single object. This is useful if you want to apply an effect to the composite object rather than to each individual object. A very common case is to apply a shadow to the composite of several objects.

Just using `CGContextDrawImage()` will composite the image onto the graphics context considering the alpha channel. Exactly how the new image is composited over any content that is already in the graphics content depends on the blend mode set for the graphics content. You set the blend mode with `CGContextSetBlendMode()`. A detailed description can be found in the [Quartz 2D Programming Guide: Bitmaps Images and Masks](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/graphicsimaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_images/dq_images.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH212-CJBIJEFG). As you can see from the reference, there are many options for how to composite the image, but I might guess that you had in mind `kCGBlendModeMultiply` or `kCGBlendModeNormal`. Note that the default is `kCGBlendModeNormal`, which just paints the source image samples over whatever is currently in the context respecting alpha values.

Comment: you're absolutely right about the transparency layer. I was experimenting looking for some way to make CG not ignore transparency.